# Configure EF Fluent API for 1-to-many but twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model as follows.

```
public class Holder
{
  ...
  public List<Thing> Future { get;set; }
  public List<Thing> Past { get;set; }
}

public class Thing 
{
  ...
  public Holder Holder { get; set; }
}
```

Now I try to use Fluent API to tell the DB that each Holder can only have many things in its future and, also, many things in the past. A thing can only be future or past but never both, so a thing is only related to a single holder but a holder may have multiple things (distributed between the two arrays).

The best of my experience was to to the following.

```
private static void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeBuilder<Thing> entity)
{
  ...
  entity.HasOne(_ => _.Holder).WithMany(_ => _.Future);
  entity.HasOne(_ => _.Holder).WithMany(_ => _.Past);
}
```

However, when I try to create a migration, EF complains about it like so.

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Holder.Future' and 'Thing.Holder', because there already is a relationship between 'Holder.Past' and 'Thing.Holder'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

I'm not sure how to resolve it the **right and proper** way. The only work-around I got to fly was to declare a class *FutureThing* and *PastThing*, effectively duplicating the source code. That's ugly and bad.

It's a bit unusual scenario and all the googling leads to the howto's for setting up simpler relations. I'm using Core 2 and I expect that there's something that facilitates this scenario.

How should I figure here?

Comment: This is not gonna work. Two collection navigation properties require two inverse reference navigation properties. Otherwise how EF Core (or database) can distinguish which Thing is Future and which - Past? The way I see it is single collection `Holder.Things` and `Thing` having enum or bool property (column) indicating if it's Future or Past.

Comment: Might it make more sense to define a Thing class with a Date property and simply filter on that? Then the Holder object would have a Things<Thing> property. You could then either filter for future dates, or have calculated properties that simply filter the main Things property by past or future dates. Without more understanding of the intended use, it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: @IvanStoev I start to see where my logic went wrong. I think boolean discriminator will be a good choice for storage. And then I can create a property that's read only, producing a filtered version of all the *Thing* instances. But then I need to prevent it from being migrated into database. I'm assuming there's a Fluen API syntax for **not** mapping stuff into DB.

Comment: @SteveBrouillard It's *future* as in *not yet done* and has no relation to time. It's rather an ambition, intention or bucket list thingy. However, based on the comment above, I realize that it's not possible to do the way I imagined. I was logically confused.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana. Ahhh...I see, something along the lines of tasks that are completed or not. Yes, I would agree with your assessment that a boolean property indicating the binary status of the thing seems to be the appropriate way to go.

Comment: best create a combined navigation property. Alternatively you can create different inverse navigation properties for "Holders I'm a past thing for" and "Holders I'm a future thing for", your properties are no proper navigation properties (because the inverse rule is ambiguous) so your approach can't work.